# Is it allowed to pass the address of a CPO as an algorithm parameter?

Tags: c++, c++20

I remember having read somewhere that since C++20 it is no longer allowed to use the address
of a function in the namespace `std`, so that new overloads of such functions can be added without
breaking user code. Does this also hold for function objects?

In particular, can customization point objects be passed as parameters of algorithms? For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <range/v3/numeric/accumulate.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m;
  
  return ranges::accumulate(m | std::views::values, 0u, std::plus{}, std::ranges::size);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to pass CPOs as parameters. They are objects with static storage duration, similar to `std::cout` etc.

The difficulty of passing overloaded functions as parameters is one of the main reasons for CPOs to exist.